# How to sign a framework?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am distributing my app and I get the error “Code signing Tor.framework failed”

How do I make it so framework is code signed?  Thanks

Comment: Sharing the structure of your project will help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Code Signing is enabled inside the Target's Settings:

[image: You should see it here]

**Edit:**
When you embed a Framework, you will have to sign it. Make sure it is listed inside Target->General->Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content and you have selected `Embed & Sign`

[image]

Comment: My framework isn’t listed as a target?  Do I add it and how?  Thanks

Comment: I already did that but framework isn’t showing up as a target. Still error.

Comment: In this case you have to select the app in Targets, not the framework. And find the framework inside Frameworks/Libraries/Embedded Content